# Powershell possible to give input to underlying script

Tags: script, git, powershell

I am sorry I could not think of a better title. My problem is I have a PowerShell script which calls a git command (git credential-wincred store) to store credentials to connect to a git repository.

When executing this command (git credential-wincred store) from a powershell script, it will give the user the possibility to write input to the git command. It expects multiple lines like below:

```
protocol=http
host=domain
username=myUsername
password=****
```

I want to automate this script, without the need for powershell to ask for user input. I know how I can pass command line parameters to the powershell script, so it is configurable, but I do not know if it is possible to pass the powershell parameters to the git command, without asking for user input.

Is it possible to write lines to the underlying git command with powershell parameters?

Comment: So basically you want it to fill out the login dialog. But why not save the credentials directly to the credential store?

Comment: I am afraid I am not very known for the different features of git credential store. I assumed this was the way to set credentials to the credential store. What other way do you suggest?

Comment: It’s not the Git credential store. It’s the Windows credential store. Luckily, [there’s a script for that](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Credentials-d44c3cde). ;)